# how to implement a audio player interface?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using AVAudioPlayer to play mp3 files, but I need to implement ui interface as shown following:
[image]

I think it maybe a iOS system control I can use, but I can't find which control it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an MPMoviePlayerController. Compare, for example this illustration from [my book](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch28.html#_mpmovieplayercontroller):

[image]

The same section of my book tells you how to make and work with one of these. Despite the name, it's great for playing audio with a user interface. The only difference between our screen shots is that you had an AirPlay device present on the network at the time.